# how to delete child inflating layout from main layout

Tags: android

how to delete child inflating layout  from main layout  my code below on click inflating view at the position .... i gotten data from sqlite data base how  to remove seleted child inflating my code is here.......

```
    LocalDataList = controller.getAllJsonData();
        viewList = new ArrayList<View>();

        main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutAddingInflater);
        parent = (ViewGroup) main.getParent();
        for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : LocalDataList) {
            System.out.println(hashMap.keySet());
            // HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {

                PositionDrugName = hashMap.get("PositionDrugName");
                strEatingDrug = hashMap.get("strEatingDrug");
                strEatingDrugNoOfDay = hashMap.get("strEatingDrugNoOfDay");
                buttonclick = hashMap.get("buttonclick");
                Log.e("Local Data", "" + hashMap.get("PositionBrand_id"));

            }

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) appContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_drug_layout_inflater, null);

            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDrugName))
                    .setText(PositionDrugName);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSaltName))
                    .setText(strEatingDrug);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDrugTime))
                    .setText(buttonclick);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDrugTimeInDay))
                    .setText(strEatingDrugNoOfDay);

            viewList.add(view);
            main.addView(view);


            for (int position=0; position<=viewList.size(); position++) {
                view.setTag(position);
            }
            view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                        try {
                              int position = 0;
                                if (v.getTag() instanceof Integer) {
                                   position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                                   Log.e("inside if  ", "inside if");
                                   Log.e("position ", ""
                                            + position);
                                   main.removeViewAt(position);
//                                 viewList.remove(position);
                                }else {
                                    Log.e("inside else  ", "inside else");
//                                  main.removeAllViews();
                                }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
            });

            // during inflation
            // viewList.add(view);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
            int position = 0;
            if (v.getTag() instanceof Integer) 
            {
                position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.e("inside if  ", "inside if");
                Log.e("position ", "" + position);
                main.removeViewAt(position);
             }
```

you can simply write:

```
            main.removeView(v);
```

### NOTE

when you remove by position, after removing the first element all indexes are now shifted, so you need to track down the number of view that you removed and update the position each time:

```
position = (Integer) v.getTag() - numOfRemovedControls;
main.removeViewAt(position);
numOfRemovedControls++;
```

Comment: how to remove from database at clicked inflated layout

Comment: i want to also remove from sqlite database  in passing inflating layout on click

Comment: that is a different question.. can you submit a new question that focus on 'db delete command' and 'sqlite' and add a link in a comments?